# How to iterate through a Map inside another Map Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map that contains data below, and I want to process the data inside the key `bookAttr`

```
{
  "form46": {
    "bookId": 46,
    "bookAttr": {
      "title": "To Kill a Mockingbird",
      "author": "Harper Lee"
    }
  },
  "form47": {
    "bookId": 66,
    "bookAttr": {
      "title": "1984",
      "author": "George Orwell"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to iterate on the initial map, however I am getting an error when trying to process the values that I have since Java is complaining that `Object cannot be converted to HashMap`

```
HashMap<String, Object> bookForm; // contains bookFormData
```

```
for (Object value : bookForm.values()) {
    HashMap<String,Object> bookAttributes = value.get("bookAttr");
    System.out.println(bookAttributes);
    //iterate over bookAttributes and do something else
}
```

How can iterate over `bookAttr` to be able to process its contents?

---

Contents of `bookForm`:

```
bookForm.entrySet().stream().forEach(e
                -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())
        );
```

Output:

```
form46={bookAttr={title=To Kill a Mockingbird, author=Harper Lee}, bookId=46}
form47={bookId=66, bookAttr={title=1984, author=George Orwell}}
```

Comment: Please provide more info about how do you get a `bookForm` map from specified JSON.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of info you need. Do you need to know where the JSON data is coming from?

Comment: No, i am about the deserialization tool you are using. Is it Jackson's `ObjectMapper`, or GSON or anything else?

Comment: I think this is using Jackson's ```ObjectMapper```

Comment: Consider debugging to inspect the type of the object you are trying to cast.  This may give you a clue as to what you are doing wrong.  If you add the deserialization code to the question it may reveal what the type should be which could get you an answer quicker.

Comment: Can you try ```HashMap<String,String> bookAttributes = (HashMap<String, String>)value.get("bookAttr");```

Comment: If your data always looks like this I would suggest to create a simple DTO representing the attributes of `bookAttr`. You then can use `Map<String, YourBookAttrDTO>` to read the json. If you don't want to create an DTO for this, I would just use the raw API Jackson provides: `JsonNode` -> `JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is that you are trying to set the `Object` value to variable of `HashMap` type. And, also try using `Map` instead of `HashMap`.

Try to replace

```
HashMap<String,Object> bookAttributes = value.get("bookAttr");
```

with

```
Map<String,Object> bookAttributes = (Map<String, Object>)value.get("bookAttr");
```